# When were the first known deployments of Phase II clone armour?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars

Phase II clone armour was developed after observing the performance of, well, Phase I clone armour in active service, and improving upon the existing design.

When were the first known uses of Phase II clone armour on the battlefield? Such as, for example, the first field testing of prototypes, the first deployment of the actual production model etc.

When are the various milestones of Phase II clone armour (and its variants for specialised troops) for "first" uses in active service?

Exploring answers from both canonicities.

Answer (score 1):

The Phase II clone armors were introduced at least as early as **in 21 BBY**. Originally they were the armor type only for the Advanced Recon Commando (ARC) troopers, but later on the entire Grand Army of the Republic was equipped with them, step by step.

I found this information by comparing [the appearances list of the armor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Phase_II_clone_trooper_armor#Appearances) in Wookieepedia to the [chronological list of the Clone Wars episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_episodes#Episodes_in_narrative_chronological_order). *Clone Cadets* appears to be the first episode (in timeline) showing the Phase II clone armor, worn by [Commander Colt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Colt) of Rancor Battalion. His ARC unit might have been one of the first troopers wearing the armor type. The cadets he trained still wore the Phase I clone armors.

Comment: Personally, I would still like to know the date the Phase II armors were beginning to be replaced with the Imperial Stormtrooper armors. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125879/when-were-the-imperial-stormtrooper-armors-introduced